# Why did the output voltage of this circuit had the same value no matter what the value for the resistor R2 was

Tags: circuit-design, temperature, thermistor

So here is the circuit:

[image]

R2 is a NTC thermistor (its value changes with temperature) and i want vout, the output of this circuit, to be in between 0.05V and 4.95V, where 0.05V should correspond to R2 with 16k and 4.95V should correspond to R2 with 5k. Every other value is in between 16k and 5k ohms.

The image below is the description of the NTC thermistor that i used in the lab, i want to read the temperatures between 15 celsius and 40 celsius.

[image]

The problem that i faced was that no matter what the resistance value was (i kept changing the temperature around it with a heater) the output voltage was always around 1,4V.
In Ltspice everything works ok, if i put R2= 8k i get vout at ~3V which is what i want.

Did that happen because of the way i dimensioned the circuit? Or did i just messed something up in the lab?

Here are 3 pics of the circuit i built in the lab:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The red and orange cables are from the NTC thermistor, the blue ones are from the power supply that gives 5V

Comment: What did the simulation result tell you?

Comment: The simulation did what the circuit what was intend to do... But i wanted to see if someone here could check out if i did anything wrong

Comment: If it worked in simulation and not in reality, for a circuit this simple, I suspect you may have messed something up wiring it up. Can you add some photos of your actual circuit and/or screenshots of the PCB design if there is one?

Comment: The simulator working is a massive oversight in your question.

Comment: So i added pics that i took in the lab

Comment: @G0tBlackOps Also, if you are having trouble in the lab, [this funny story](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~kovar/hall.html) may bring a chuckle.

Comment: @jonk Wonderful story, made me laugh out loud! ;-)

Comment: @G0tBlackOps Have you analyzed your circuit mathematically already?

Comment: @Jan yes i did.

Comment: How did you measure 1.4V from the output? With the MCU board? How is the MCU board supposed to measure anything, if only one wire connects to it? What other parts have you measured to see if voltages are what you expect?

Comment: Did you probe your circuit, with a voltmeter, to see what voltage levels are present?  First I would probe the junction of R3/R4.  Then the junction of R2/R1.  Then the output of U2.  Maybe replace R2 (the thermistor) with a pot or some different fixed value resistors.  Slice and dice.  I bet you have a wiring error or wrong component value.

Comment: @Justme You might be onto something... I just connected the vout to the analog input of the arduino, i didnt connect anything to ground. Could it be because of that?

Comment: Yes.  Both your circuit & the Arduino need to have a common ground, or point of reference.  Like Elliot Alderson said - this is why it's hard to provide good advice looking at pictures of a breadboard.

Comment: @G0tBlackOps Do you think it would work with one wire, if it was powered with a floating supply, like batteries?

Comment: @Justme Honestly i didn't even think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely reason, the breadboard is powered with a floating power supply, so there is no common ground reference between the MCU and op-amps.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately upon looking at your photos, I think this resistor may be inserted one hole off from where it should be:

[image]

Comment: That's a bad angle, in the third picture you can see they are connected

Comment: @G0tBlackOps That's why you shouldn't expect people to look over photos of your breadboard.